# Render parent background-image property underneath child div content

Tags: css

I have a div structure in CSS that looks something like this.

```
<div style="background-image: url(my_url.ext)>
    <div>
        My content 1.
    <div>
    <div>
        My content 2.
    <div>
</div>
```

When the site is displayed on mobile, I want the background-image property to display below the content divs. I tried using the background-position attribute but it did not extend the length of the parent div and in effect hid the image. Is there a way to do this without setting a separate `<img>` tag inside the parent `<div>`? My CSS class currently looks something like this:

```
.myClass/root {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

@media (desktop-breakpoint) {
    .myClass/root {
        position: relative;
    }

    .myClass/root .myClass/background {
        background-size: cover;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: -1;
    }
}

@media (mobile-breakpoint) {
    .myClass/root {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    .myClass/root .myClass/background {
        background-size: cover;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure what you are after - are you just wanting the background image to fill the whole of the parent div? if so, use `background-size:cover`

Comment: @Pete On desktop, the background is doing what I want it to do. When I switch to mobile, however, I want the background image of the parent div to render underneath the content divs

Comment: @Pete kind of, but the background image right now is a parent of the parent div because on desktop I want the background behind the content divs, but on mobile I want the background below the content divs.

Comment: sorry see edit to my comment above

Comment: @Pete this is working for desktop but on mobile it is still cutting off the image. It's as if the parent div is not expanding to handle it.

Comment: did you add the height to the html and body tags?

Comment: @Pete yes, the height attribute is set.

Comment: Sorry then Dan, I am unable to help anymore without a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
#parent{
  height:auto;
  width: auto;
  color:#fff;
  position:relative;
}
#parent:after{
  content: "";
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  background-position:center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/110147/pexels-photo-110147.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb);
  z-index:-1;
}

@media(max-width: 767px){
  #parent div{
    background: #000;
  }
  #parent:after{
  content: "";
  height:50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display:block;
  background-position:center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/110147/pexels-photo-110147.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb);
  z-index: 50;
}
}
```

while your html as follows

```
<div id="parent">
    <div>
        My content 1.
    </div>
    <div>
        My content 2.
    </div>
</div>
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nalbayrak/zgo7ta01/)

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work. It causes the other contents on the page to hide the parent div while in desktop mode and in mobile the same problem occurs where the image does not display.

Comment: can you check fiddle and tell me which part is not working? I dont get same results